# How does function parameters and local variables affect on the performance of a C program

Tags: c, performance

is it worth to reduce the number of function parameters and local variables to enhance the performance of a C program?

in the provided code below, maybe the example doesn't make a difference if the function is called few times during the execution but maybe it make sense if it's called **n times**, so is there any performance benefits in this case?

```
int n[4];
// read numbers ...

do_sum1(n[0], n[1], n[2], n[4]);
do_sum2(n);

// Functions definition
// --------------------
void do_sum1(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
  printf("%d\n", a + b + c + d);
}

void do_sum2(int n[4])
{
  printf("%d\n", n[0] + n[1] + n[2] + n[3]);
}
```

Comment: There is only one and single true way to find out. Compare the generated assembly code. And keep in mind that you are really comparing a specific variation of code+compiler+compiler options.

Comment: If you can *actually* measure any performance difference with an optimized build, I'll be surprised.

Comment: But why *would* you use the first example, which passes all the array elements individually? It's unlikely to be faster anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane as I argue in my answer, at least in theory first case should be faster.

Comment: I also disagree with VTCs. The question is neither opinion based, nor is it too broad.

Comment: @SergeyA I see, but that depends on having a specific hardware. Leave it to the compiler to sort it out.

Comment: @WeatherVane specific hardware means x64. (Quite possible other platforms as well, I am just not familiar). I would call it as generic as it gets. Also, compiler will not optimize it out for you.

Comment: @KamilCuk: No, that is not a way to find out. It would only tell you what the difference is in a very specific situation—for one program compiled with one compiler run on one processor with one set of input. Even if you timed many different runs, it would not answer the question in general. Nor is it generally easy to predict program execution time from assembly code. Different processors in the same architecture execute the same instruction sequence differently. Even in one processor, the execution time may be dependent on prior activity.

Comment: @SergeyA AFAIK most processors in commercial use are not 64-bit platforms. And at what length of array do you make the decision? Let the compiler tailor the code for the processor.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am not sure what the statistics is. From what I see day-to-day, x64 and ARM trump everything else. While I do not know anything about ARM ABI, I would be super-surprised if ARM doesn't support a fast parameter passing through register, register stacks or similar mechanism. If you have some data to back up your assumptions, I'd be very eager to see it.

Comment: If these functions are called from a function inside this same compilation unit, they will likely be inlined and produce [exactly the same output](https://godbolt.org/z/sRoHi0). With extern linkage, i.e. called from a different module, the one with explicit parameters could use 4 registers depending on the architecture. Making it `static inline` and moving to a header file will basically be the safest bet, performance wise, but possibly unnecessary - the only sure way to know the difference is to benchmark it in the actual application which presumably calls it lots of times.

Comment: @SergeyA isn't the main point to use the best practice to write code? C is processor-agnostic. Who unrolls an array? If it is approrpiate, why use an array in the first place?

Comment: @WeatherVane it is never a point to use **best practices**. It is always a point to write correct code which gives optimal balance of performance vs code maintainability, readability and human effort. It is a true fact that `do_sum1` generates different (and more performant!) assembly than `do_sum2` on x64 ABI.  If your goal is to shave away every nanosecond possible (which is the case in some environments) you should know that `do_sum1` is preferred.

Comment: @SergeyA if that were my goal I would be using assembler.

Comment: As an aside, first I'd check if you are not going to be using it outside the compilation unit; `static` functions are trivially optimised.

Answer (score 8):

The question is trickier than it seems.

First of, let's assume the function is not inlined (as otherwise they are more than likely to be compiled to the same code) and let's analyze the effect.

From one hand, the number of parameters to function affects the performance. **All other things being equal**, the more parameters are passed, the worse the performance  - since copying parameters to the place function expects to find them (be it a stack, a register or any other storage) takes non-0 time.

From the other hand, semantic matters, and in this particular case, things are not equal! In your first case, you are passing 4 integer parameters. Assuming AMD64 ABI, they will be passed in CPU registers - which are super-fast to be accessed for both reading and writing.

However, in the second case you are effectively passing a pointer to a memory location. Which means, accessing values through this pointer means indirection, and at best the values would be found in L1 CPU cache (most likely), but at worst will be read from main memory (super slow!). While L1 cache is fast, it is still much slower when compared to register access.

Bottom line:

I expect the second case to be slower, than the first one.

Comment: May the venerable downvoter explain their downvote?

Answer (score 1):

> is it worth to reduce the number of function parameters and local variables to enhance the performance of a C program?

The first question to ask is, *will* it enhance the performance of your program?  Will it make a measurable difference at all?  Don't blindly assume that it will.

The second question to ask is, what are the tradeoffs of doing so?  How will it affect your ability to debug and maintain your code?  Yes, you could make everything global to eliminate passing parameters and using locals, but the effect of that will be to make your code *much* harder to understand and maintain.

When thinking about improving performance, you should start from the highest level and work your way down:

1. Are you using the right data structures and/or algorithms for the problem at hand?  For example, an unoptimized quicksort will still beat the pants off an aggressively tuned bubble sort (in the average case), binary searches are usually faster than linear searches, etc.
2. Are you using the appropriate tools or libraries, or are you hand-hacking everything yourself?  It's possible there's already a solution out there that's been tested and tuned, such that you don't have to write from scratch.
3. Have you implemented your design well?  For example, do you have any invariants in your loop bodies?

If the answer to all of those question is "yes", then the next step is to let the compiler do some optimizing (such as using the `-O2` flag with gcc).  C compilers have gotten very good at optimizing code, and depending on the program you can see some significant speedup.

If at this point you still feel your code is too slow, then you need to do some analysis.  Run the code through a profiler to find where the bottlenecks are.  *At this point*, you can start to look at micro-optimizations like reducing the number of parameters being passed to a function.  Just be aware that it may not make enough of a difference to be worth the effort.

Comment: *It's possible there's already a solution out there that's been tested and tuned, such that you don't have to write from scratch* and remain a brainless copy-paste machine? No, thank you very much.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer: If you're hand-hacking your own XML parser when libxml is *right there* you're wasting time and effort that could be better spent working on your actual problem.  I can say that because I've *done* it, more than once.  Unless you're doing it to educate yourself or because you've figured out a better/more performant solution, there's no reason to constantly re-invent the wheel.